# Using StatefulWidget List having FutureBuilder as child shows no data till i hot reload and then calls future with no data immediately

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, statefulwidget, flutter-hotreload

I have a stateful widget which will show list of products, data will be fetched from api so I used future builder. Here problem is I can see data in log but not on widget class, it shows length 0 of list but as soon as I reload data shows for second and then show data length is 0. I have seen some links on  [Showing data on second hot reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59889062/future-builder-having-data-on-second-hot-reload) and [Data showing after hot reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535761/data-is-showing-only-after-i-hot-reload-or-refresh-in-flutter). But I have tried them but no luck now I have no idea what they were trying to tell. Tell me where I should look at to see the error.

```
    class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: CartBloc().getCartList(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Cart>> snapShot) {
              //logd("cart data -> ${snapShot.data.length}");
              if (snapShot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapShot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                        child: Dismissible(
                          key: Key(snapShot.data[index].product.id.toString()),
                          direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                          onDismissed: (direction) {
                            setState(() {
                              snapShot.data.removeAt(index);
                            });
                          },
                          background: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xFFFFE6E6),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Spacer(),
                                SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/Trash.svg"),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: CartCard(cart: snapShot.data[index]),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              } else {
                return Center(
                    child: Text("Looks like you haven't purcahsed anything"));
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit 1: getCartList function.

```
Future<List<Cart>> getCartList(){
  List<Cart> cartItems=List<Cart>();
    Future<List<GetCartModal>> data= cartRepo.getCart();
    //data.then((value) => logd("cart respo => $value"));
   data.then((value) => logd("cart respo -> ${value.length}"));
   return data.then((value) {
      for(var cartData in value)
      ProductsBloc().getProductDetails(cartData.sku).then((cartItem) {
        cartItems.add(Cart(numOfItem:cartData.qty,product: Product(cartData.itemId,cartItem.sku,cartItem.images,cartItem.title,cartItem.price,cartItem.description) ));
      });
      return cartItems;
    });
  }
```

getCart() in Cart repository:

```
 Future<List<GetCartModal>> getCart() async{
     String url =club(CART_LISTING);
     Future<String> data= Sf.getStringValuesSF(USER_TOKEN);
     data.then((value) => logd("token -> $value"));
     ///await to halt execution till token found.
     var header={'Authorization':"Bearer ${await Sf.getStringValuesSF(USER_TOKEN)}",'accept': 'application/json'};
    final response = await _apiClinet.get(Uri.parse(url),headers: header);
    //logd("cart response => $response");
    return (json.decode(jsonEncode(response)) as List).map((i) =>
              GetCartModal.fromJson(i)).toList();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Stream Builder" I think it will get the latest data as stream and update the UI of your screen.

Comment: Is there any problem with future builder i mean my data is not continuous, this is just a json having a list. otherwise i will have a fundamental question where to use future builder and where stream builder.

Comment: Can you share the code for this: CartBloc().getCartList()

Comment: i edited the question, please take a look